# The mutable variable 'i' is used in an invalid way.?

Tags: f#

I am attempting to write some simple code in F#, and i get this error:

```
Error   1   The mutable variable 'i' is used in an invalid way. Mutable variables may not be captured by closures. Consider eliminating this use of mutation or using a heap-allocated mutable reference cell via 'ref' and '!'
```

Code:

```
let printProcess = async {
        let mutable i = 1;
        while true do
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);//error is here
            i <- i + 1;
    }
```

Why won't it let me print the variable?

Comment: It's been a while since this was asked, but it should be noted that this error **is not raised anymore**. Due to changes in how `mutable` is treated, reference cells have mostly become obsolete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't refer to mutables inside a closure, and that includes such constructs as seq{} and async{} blocks.

You could write

```
let printProcess = async {
        let i = ref 1
        while true do
            System.Console.WriteLine(!i)
            i := !i + 1
    }
```

See [this blog](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!689.entry) for some discussion.

Comment: The short answer for why you have to do this is that 'mutable' values are on the stack and 'ref' values are on the heap. Since the stack frame will be cleared as soon as the function exits all mutable values get reclaimed. Ref values on the other hand will persist just like any other garbage collected object.

Comment: Another way to put it is that F# captures values, not variables. Because of this, capturing the value of a mutable variable would be the same as capturing the value of an immutable variable, as the value itself is always immutable. This behaviour is probably not what people would expect, and was therefore forbidden.