# remove characters from string in f#

Tags: string, replace, f#

I have a `List<char>` in `stripchars`. These characters should not be present in string `text`. So I've made that mutable.

So I do something like:

```
stripchars |> Seq.iter(
    fun x ->
        text <- text.Replace(x, ' ')
    )
```

Then I get an error saying text is a mutable variable used in an invalid way. Now I go and look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1480582/145682) post, and I come out with something like

```
let s = ref text    
stripchars |> Seq.iter(
    fun ch ->
        printfn "ch: %c" ch
        printfn "resultant: %s" !s
        s :=  (!s).Replace(ch, ' ')
    )
```

This still doesn't accomplish mutating the state of `text`. What is the correct way?

Comment: see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_a_set_of_characters_from_a_string#F.23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As F# belongs to .NET stack we may rely upon the power of platform libraries. <del>Then this character stripping task can be achieved as simple as</del>

<del>`open System

open System.Linq

let stripChars chars (text:string) = String.Concat(text.Except(stripChars))`</del>

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately, later on I've realized that [Enumerable.Except method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) produces the **set difference** of two sequences, meaning `stripChars "a" "ababab"` would be just `"b"` instead of expected `"bbb"`.

Continuing in LINQ venue the correctly working implementation may be more wordy:

```
let stripv1 (stripChars: seq<char>) (text:string) =
    text.Where(fun (c: char) -> not(stripChars.Contains(c))) |> String.Concat
```

which probably do not worth effort compared with equivalent idiomatic F#:

```
let stripv2 (stripChars: seq<char>) text =
    text |> Seq.filter(fun c -> not (stripChars.Contains c)) |> String.Concat
```

So, a pure .NET-specific approach would be to follow [Ruben's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11635/ruben-bartelink) advice regarding `String.Split`from the comment below:

```
let stripv3 (stripChars:string) (text:string) =
    text.Split(stripChars.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) |> String.Concat
```

Comment: +1 or abuse [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) :) (was coming back to post that until you updated this)

Answer (score 6):

Since no one has posted this yet, the [`Core.String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx) module contains the methods you're looking for.

To replace the given characters with a space (or any other given single character), use [`String.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353653.aspx):

```
let strip chars = String.map (fun c -> if Seq.exists((=)c) chars then ' ' else c)

strip "xyz" "123x4y5z789" // 123 4 5 789
```

To remove the given characters entirely, use [`String.collect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340454.aspx):

```
let strip chars = String.collect (fun c -> if Seq.exists((=)c) chars then "" else string c)

strip "xyz" "123x4y5z789" // 12345789
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using Seq.fold

```
Seq.fold (fun (str: string) chr -> str.Replace(chr, ' ')) "Hello world" stripchars
```

Fold is very powerful. It can be used in many a situation where you want to repeatedly change something.

Also, don't you want to actually *remove* characters; not just replace them with spaces? If so, you should use this instead:

```
let stripchars chars str =
  Seq.fold
    (fun (str: string) chr ->
      str.Replace(chr |> Char.ToUpper |> string, "").Replace(chr |> Char.ToLower |> string, ""))
    str chars
```

Also, this solution is case-insensitive.

Comment: No I actually want to remove them

Comment: Hold on, for some reason the second gives a compile error... Trying to fix it

Comment: Done; fixed it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
let doStrip (stripChars: char list) (text:string) =
    text |> String.map (fun c -> if stripChars |> List.contains c then ' ' else c)
    
    
    
let doStrip' (stripChars: string) (text:string) =
    text |> String.map (fun c -> if stripChars.Contains c then ' ' else c)
```